# How to use Graphql typescript types in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql

I have a react app with a keystone.js backend and a graphql api

I have a list of products in keystones.js and a simple graphql query

```
import gql from "graphql-tag";

export const ALL_PRODUCTS_QUERY = gql`
    query ProductData{
        allProducts{
            id
            price
            description
            name
        }
    }
`
```

I'm using apollo codegen to generate the types for the graphql so I get

```
export interface ProductData_allProducts {
  __typename: "Product";
  id: string;
  price: number | null;
  description: string | null;
  name: string | null;
}

export interface ProductData {
  /**
   *  Search for all Product items which match the where clause. 
   */
  allProducts: (ProductData_allProducts | null)[] | null;
}
```

In React I can list the products and use the types in the code, here I'm using `<ProductData>`

```
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/client";
import {ALL_PRODUCTS_QUERY} from '../queries/index'
import { ProductData } from "../generated/ProductData";

const Products = () => {

    const {data, error, loading} = useQuery<ProductData>(ALL_PRODUCTS_QUERY)
    if(loading) return <p>Loading</p>
    if(error) return <p>Error: {error.message}</p> 

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                {data?.allProducts?.map(product => (
                    <div>{product?.name}</div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Products;
```

Instead of using `<div>{product?.name}</div>` I would like to create a `Product` component

```
import React from 'react';
import { ProductData, ProductData_allProducts } from '../generated/ProductData';

const Product = ({product}:ProductData_allProducts) => {
    return (
        <p>{product.name}</p>
    );
};

export default Product;
```

but what should the type be for `product` here I get an error saying

```
Property 'product' does not exist on type 'ProductData_allProducts'.
```

and on the Products page

```
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/client";
import {ALL_PRODUCTS_QUERY} from '../queries/index'
import { ProductData } from "../generated/ProductData";
import Product from "./Product";


const Products = () => {

    const {data, error, loading} = useQuery<ProductData>(ALL_PRODUCTS_QUERY)
    if(loading) return <p>Loading</p>
    if(error) return <p>Error: {error.message}</p> 

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                {data?.allProducts?.map(product => (
                    <Product product={product} />
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Products;
```

I now get an error on the product prop

```
Type '{ product: ProductData_allProducts | null; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ProductData_allProducts'.
  Property 'product' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ProductData_allProducts'.
```

So what should the types be on the Product page when passing in the product

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution

You can fix the error by changing your code like this:

```
const Product = ({ product }: { product: ProductData_allProducts }) => {
  return <p>{product.name}</p>;
};
```

### Explanation

The problem was that you typed the `props` of the component as type `ProductComponentProps`, all the while you only wanted to type the property `props.product` as that. So your code basically looked like this:

```
const Product = (props: ProductData_allProducts) => {
  return (
      <p>{product.name}</p>
  );
};
```

And as all the properties like `name` or `description` where missing, *Typescript* complained about it. Here is a working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/https-stackoverflow-com-questions-70528857-how-to-use-graphql-typescript-types-in-react-031bn?file=/src/App.tsx:155-262) for you to check out.

Answer (score 1):

Does the following work for you?

```
interface ProductComponentProps {
    product: ProductData_allProducts
}


const Product = ({product}: ProductComponentProps) => {
    return (
        <p>{product.name}</p>
    );
};
```

Comment: That does work, but these types are generated by `apollo codegen` so I thought I shouldn't have to do something like this

Comment: where I use the component and pass in the `product` I get `Type 'ProductData_allProducts | null' is not assignable to type 'ProductData_allProducts'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'ProductData_allProducts'.`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to destructure a property that doesnt exist on the type.
This should work:

```
type Product = {
  __typename: "Product";
  id: string;
  price: number | null;
  description: string | null;
  name: string | null;
};

const ProductComponent: FC<Product> = ({ name }) => {
  return <p>{name}</p>;
};

export default ProductComponent;
```

Comment: I'm using `product` instead of `name` but I'm still getting `Property 'product' does not exist on type 'PropsWithChildren<ProductData_allProducts>'`

Comment: I'm using `ProductData_allProducts` instead of your `Product` because they are the same

Comment: yea you can use your type ( its the same)

Comment: but I still get the same error

Comment: take a look i made an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-forest-ljjgs?file=/src/App.tsx